# Make form submit with addition parameters. ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I would like to submit form by click on the button 'Submit'. All ok, but I have addition checkboxes without binding to model. This checkboxes were added dynamically. How to send form to client with these checkboxes and grab data on server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[HttpPost]

public ActionResult Add(PremiumSlots PremiumSlots, FormCollection collection)
        {

```
        string chkbx = collection["yes-no"];
```

// "yes-no" name of checkbox (Should be same for all checkboxes)

```
       // you will get comma separated values, perform split operation on string  and use individualy
```

}